# Split string in 2 variables but give one variable 2/3 the words

Tags: php, sql, regex

I want to split a string into 2 variables, but give one variable about 75% of the words from the string and the other variable 25%.

I have this code which splits a paragraph from the database in 2, but now I need to give one part 2/3 the words and the other part 1/3 the words. Is this even possible:

Here's my current code:

```
$pagetext = mysql_result($result, $i, "column");
$thewordamt = str_word_count($pagetext);
$halfwords = $thewordamt / 2;

function limit_words($string, $word_limit) {
    $words = explode(" ", $string);
    return implode(" ", array_splice($words, 0, $word_limit));
}

$start = limit_words($pagetext, $halfwords); //first part
$end = str_replace($start, '', $pagetext); //second part
```

Comment: Stop using the **deprecated and as of PHP7 removed** `mysql_*` functions. Migrate to PDO and start using Prepared Statements.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: explode into an array, then split the array wherever the 2/3rd point is

Comment: `$halfwords = ($thewordamt * 2) / 3;` however you may want to change variable name.

Comment: Shorter: I want to split a string into 2 variables, but give one variable about 75% of the words from the string and the other variable 25%.

Answer (score 1):

I think this explains itself:

```
$txt = "I met him on a Monday and my heart stood still
Da do ron-ron-ron, da do ron-ron
Somebody told me that his name was Bill
Da do ron-ron-ron, da do ron-ron";

$parts = daDoRunRun($txt, 0.33);

printf('<p>%s</p><p>%s</p>', $parts['short'], $parts['long']);


function daDoRunRun($txt, $short_part_percentage) {
    $split_index = floor(str_word_count($txt)*$short_part_percentage);
    $words = explode(' ', $txt);

    return [
        'short' => join(' ', array_splice($words, 0, $split_index)),
        'long' => join(' ', $words)
    ];
}
```